# Trying to solve a Ramanujan integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve the following Ramanujan integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(2mx)}{\prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x^2}{(k+a)^2}\right)}\mathrm dx=\frac12\sqrt\pi\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12+a\right)}{\Gamma(a)}\text{sech}^{2a}(m).
\end{equation*}
I will clarify my steps as follows:

Step 1) I noted that:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(2mx)}{\prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x^2}{(k+a)^2}\right)}\mathrm dx&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2mx)}{\prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x^2}{(k+a)^2}\right)}\mathrm dx\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\binom{a+ix-1}{a-1}\binom{a-ix-1}{a-1}\frac{x\cos(2mx)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\mathrm dx\tag{2},
\end{align*}
where in (1) I used the known result $\displaystyle \prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{b^2}{(k+a)^2}\right)=\frac{\Gamma^2(a)}{\Gamma(a+ib)\Gamma(a-ib)}$.

Step 2) To develop the integral in (2) I used the result:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{\left(1+e^{iz}\right)^n}{e^{ikz}}\mathrm dz=\binom{n}{k}
\end{equation*}
and then using this, i arrived in:
\begin{align*}
(2)=\frac{1}{8\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{\left(1+e^{iz}\right)^{a-1}}{e^{i(a-1)z}}\frac{\left(1+e^{i\theta}\right)^{a-1}}{e^{i(a-1)\theta}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1+e^{iz}}{1+e^{i\theta}}\right)^{ix}\frac{x\cos(2mx)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\mathrm dx\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dz.\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Well, it is not difficult to prove that:
\begin{equation*}
\therefore\quad\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1+e^{iz}}{1+e^{i\theta}}\right)^{ix}\frac{x\cos(2mx)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\mathrm dx=\frac1{4}\left\{\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{2m+\omega}{2}\right)+\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{2m-\omega}{2}\right)\right\},
\end{equation*}
here $\displaystyle \omega=\ln\left(
\frac{1+e^{iz}}{1+e^{i\theta}}\right)$. Lastly, I connected this in (3).

And here the problem arises, at the moment I don't have many ideas that can work to complete the result of the main integral. I have already seen two other proofs for this Ramanujan integral, but I am interested in this approach. I thank anyone who can illuminate the last step, especially.

Comment: Congrat, your edit happened a second before my down click :-) So I click up.

Comment: Haha, thank you @peterh!

Comment: Someone??????????

Comment: Did you check Ramanujan's proof in his paper *Some definite integrals*, Messenger of Mathematics, XLIV, 1915, 10-18? He used partial fractions to split integrand into a number of simpler functions and then used term by term integration. Justification for term by term integration is not given by Ramanujan, but apart from that the whole procedure is rather straightforward.

Comment: +1 for showing your effort. People need to learn from you.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, i have seen the Ramanujan test and I also found it simple and brilliant. However, I wanted to provide something different, but I can see that my last integral is not good. I still have hope to continue, but the truth is that I have no idea how to proceed with the last integral.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. @ParamandSingh. I follow your website, you are a reference in the study of elliptical functions for me.